# Replace a delimiter by html tag in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a way to replace a string as the following:

Original string:

```
|Hello||everybody|, I am |human|
```

And result:

```
<span>Hello</span><span>everybody</span>, I am <span>human</span>
```

Is there a simple way to replace this original string to this result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `explode`

Comment: i saw 3 downvotes. Please give me a reason for downvote. It look quite simple question but not easy as you guys think.

Comment: This is not a question, it is a request to do something for you. That is not a  proper post on SO. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks. You mean, i should update my question with all the solutions i am tried?

Comment: It doesn't have to be everything. Show *at least some* effort and how close you have been to actual solution, what was unclear and at what point you needed help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace(
    "~\|(.+)\|~U",
    "<span>$1</span>",
    $yourString
);
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/Src0X8).

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92, honestly i am not have many knowledge about regex. With 3 downvotes, i learned too much about how to ask a question. Your regex is run very nice. Thanks again

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh You should have taken a look around at some of the questions tagged with [php & regex](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aq) first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at regexp, so here is an other code:

```
$string = "|Hello||everybody|, I am |human|";
$arr = explode("|", $string);
$result = "";
$span = "<span>";
$span_close = "</span>";
foreach($arr as $element){
    if(strlen($element) > 0){
        $result .= $span.$element.$span_close;
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Your solutions is same with one of solutions what i am tried. Result is not exactly right because some string not included in <span> tag

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh What do you mean by "not included"? When I run this script, the result is:
<span>Hello</span><span>everybody</span><span>, I am </span><span>human</span>